# Test drive on flutter: android.jar file not found

Tags: android, debugging, flutter, dart

I'm just trying to run the first app and this is what happens:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > File 'C:\Users\XXXX\Appdata\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar' specified for property 'androidJar' does not exist.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

The file is on the android-29 folder! what should I do?

Answer (score 3):

This error might occur because of `android.jar` is in another folder

Try opening

> C:\Users\XXXX\Appdata\Local\Android\sdk\platforms

and then look
for a folder named android-29 or android-27 and you should be able to find `android.jar` in that folder just copy that file and paste it into to android-28

Comment: This answer worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

> [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTCBw.jpg) Please update your android sdk.

You don't have install api 28.
Please open your android sdk and install android sdk 28.

Answer (score 0):

Not only `android.jar` is missing from my `android-xx` folder, then copy `android.jar` from other folder could solve this problem but I still have another problems when combine.
So I do a workaround

- First, I delete this `android-xx` folder from `Android\sdk\platforms`
- Then, I create a new empty project
- Next, inside `app\build.gradle` of new project, I set both `compileSdk` and `targetSdk` to `xx`
- Sync and run new project
- Finally, `android-xx` will contains all the files

I dont know if delete the old `android-xx` before create new project is required or not. but I deleted it to make sure their is no other problem when replacing file

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, `android.jar` is't automatically downloaded or built when installing specific Android SDK versions. This oversight means Flutter cannot find the `android.jar`, since it doesn't exist.

One solution, after installing the SDK version, is to manually download the `android.jar` for your desired SDK version from the following GitHub repository:

https://github.com/Sable/android-platforms

Make sure to put the `android.jar` file in the correct location, replacing `XX` with your version number:

**Windows**

`C:\Users\XXXX\Appdata\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-XX\android.jar`

**OS X**

`Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-XX/android.jar`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was solved using the following steps.

1. JDK is not installed on my machine; I have installed it.
2. After I faced the issue, android.jar was not found in the android-33 folder. I deleted the android-33 and The app started working.